# Applying two animations in the same animation xml file

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I would like to know if it is possible to apply one animation with two scale animations in the same xml file lets say I have

animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <alpha
       android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
       android:toAlpha = "0.5"
       android:duration = "300">
   </alpha>
   <scale
       android:fromXScale = "1"
       android:toXScale = "1.3"
       android:fromYScale = "1"
       android:toYScale = "1.3"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration = "50">
   </scale>

   <scale
       android:fromXScale = "1"
       android:toXScale = "1.3"
       android:fromYScale = "1"
       android:toYScale = "1.3"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration = "50">
   </scale>
```

then apply this animation on an ImageView in a way so it does animation 1 then animation 2?

instead of creating two seperate animations and adding an animation listener to my first animation to execute animation2 when one is finished...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use:

```
 android:ordering="sequentially"
```

for the set so it animating sequentially. take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) for further information.

Comment: already tried this, does not work when applying it to an animation set as mentioned above

Comment: you can also use nested `set`. I think if  you read the link you will find your way :-)

Comment: read the reference link documentation: "ViewAnimation" https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But the important thing is, time Duration you are setting for the animation. you can do something like this.

```
Animation multipleAnimaiton;
       imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    multipleAnimaiton= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation);
                    bounceAnimation.setDuration(5000);
                    v.startAnimation(bounceAnimation);

                }
            });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            StartAnimation1();
            StartAnimation2();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void StartAnimation1() {

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_logo);

    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
}

private void StartAnimation2() {
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
    anim.reset();
    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.re_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.sequential);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_logo_name);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Hope it helps